# Cannot connect to APEX installed PDB through Liquibase command

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, liquibase, sqlcl, oracle21c

I have installed Oracle database 21c(XE) on my local and installed Oracle Apex on 'XEPDB1'. After installing Liquibase and sqlcli, I logged in to user in XEPDB1 and tried to export Apex code using following command but it looked for the user in Xe or ORCL. Can anybody help?

```
D:\Software\sqlcl-latest\sqlcl\bin>sql


SQLcl: Release 23.1 Production on Mon May 01 14:13:37 2023

Copyright (c) 1982, 2023, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Username? (''?) apexschema@xepdb1
Password? (**********?) ***********
Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

SQL> lb generate-apex-object  -applicationid 100
--Starting Liquibase at 14:14:17 (version 4.17.0 #0 built at 2022-11-02 21:48+0000)

  USER          = apexschema
  URL           = jdbc:oracle:oci8:@
  Error Message = ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
  USER          = apexschema
  URL           = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl
  Error Message = Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
  (CONNECTION_ID=6gv3AlqBTtaD1dBjIbKGxQ==)
  USER          = apexschema
  URL           = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe
  Error Message = ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

SQL>
```

Comment: That definitely smells like a bug, does his work if you provide the connection properties when you start sqlcl, say sql apexschema@localhost:1521/xepdb1 and then do the lb generate-apex-object command?

Comment: Hi @Jeff, Thanks for the comment. Yes, I input the connection properties for 'xepdb1'. So, do I need to raise a request for this bug? From whom do I need to ask?

Comment: I would log the bug for you, but it's working for me, well, i tested with lb generate-object for a table vs an apex app

Comment: @Jeff, Thanks for submitting a bug for me. I also tried lb generate-schema -split. But still gives the same error.